# merging large excel files in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have 20 excel files each is about 26 MB. I want to merge all these 20 files into one file in python. Please note that the variables order may not be the same in all the files and some variables might me missing in one file and might be present in another. Can someone help?

Comment: Excel files are hard to read in Python, if you export the Excel data to a .csv file you can read it using the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)
And of course you can then write it as well, just row by row.

Comment: Far too broad in scope. [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/62576)